# References for modular curves over finite fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, elliptic-curves, modular-forms, finite-fields

I'm looking for a detailed reference for modular curves over finite fields, such as $X(N)$, $X_1(N)$, and $X_0(N)$. There seems to be a lot of literature dealing with them over $\mathbb{C}$, but I'm specifically interested in them from the perspective of algebraic geometry. Also, do there exist tables of their point counts over $\mathbb{F}_q$ for some small (but hopefully at least up to $N=15$ or so) values of $N$, or algorithms (e.g. in Sage) for calculating such information? For genus 0 the Riemann hypothesis for curves over finite fields gives an exact formula, of course.

Comment: Do not crosspost: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339197/modular-curves-over-finite-fields.

Comment: Sorry about that! I wasn't aware of the policy.

Comment: Since it has been answered on Math.SE, maybe this question should be closed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this was answered on math.stackexchange.